# created object which store patient information. need to use it throughout the application

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I need to find a way to make an object which stores patient information "global" to my application in objective c. Example, class A creates the object, (its basically a user name/ password screen). When they close out the application, I would like the appdelegate's applicationdidEnterBackground to read information from this object(which was created in Class A).

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options:

1. Make your object a property on your App Delegate
2. Make it a [singleton](http://www.johnwordsworth.com/2010/04/iphone-code-snippet-the-singleton-pattern/)

Comment: singleton make sense. However, if you were in this situation,what would you use? I mean there are so many ways to skin a cat here.. would would you use ?

Comment: @user3096898 isn't that more of a design choice. Please clarify your question

Comment: @user3096898, I would use a singleton, just to avoid adding extraneous responsibilities to the app delegate.

Answer (score 1):

1. One of the options is to create a singleton: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/Singleton.html
2. You can also simply write that data inside NSUserDefaults or to a file, a read it afterwards - if you are using this only occasionally it's better idea.
3. Make this as a public property of your view and read it from appdelegate - however this is not best option if you later change the view to be a subview or you also lose this object when you gets deallocated.

Answer (score 0):

singleton is the way:

you can make class as UserdataSingleton which overrides NSObject. which you can use all over your application to share data globally (for your case array). this code template may help you:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

@interface UserDataSingleton : NSObject

{
    @private
    NSArray *globalArray;
}

+(UserDataSingleton *) getInstance;
-(void)saveInUserDatasingletonWithArray:(NSArray *)array;
-(NSDictionary *)getGlobalArray;

@end

and implementation file will be some thing like:

```
#import "UserDataSingleton.h"
```

@implementation UserDataSingleton

static UserDataSingleton *userDataSingletonInstance;

+(UserDataSingleton *) getInstance
{

```
if (userDataSingletonInstance == nil)   {
 userDataSingletonInstance = [[UserDataSingleton alloc] init];
```

}
    return userDataSingletonInstance; 
}

-(void)saveInUserDatasingletonWithArray:(NSArray *)array 
{
    globalArray = array; 
}
-(NSDictionary *)getGlobalDictionary 
{ 
    return globalArray; 
} 
@end

usage:

```
#import "UserDataSingleton.h"
```

## define USERDATASINGLETON (UserDataSingleton *)[UserDataSingleton getInstance]

......................your code...

NSArray *this_IS_Array_Populated_here_For_Global_Access = [NSArray alloc] initWith....];

[USERDATASINGLETON saveInUserDatasingletonWithArray:this_IS_Array_Populated_here_For_Global_Access];//you put your array for global access.

later some where in any other view or view controller you can get that global array for example lets say you have YourViewController class:

```
NSMutableArray *yourArrayFromWebResponse = [USERDATASINGLETON getGlobalArray];
```